# Sqlite3 runtime error: foreign key constraint failed (19)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database with 2 tables `messages` and `chats`.

`.schema messages`

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "messages"
(
    "id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "role" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "content" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "message_index" INTEGER NULL,
    "chat_id" TEXT NOT NULL REFERENCES chats(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    "previous_message" INTEGER NULL REFERENCES messages(id)
);
```

`.schema chats`

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "chats"
(
    "id" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "message_count" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT(0),
    "is_locked" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT(0) CHECK("is_locked" IN(0, 1)),
    "title" TEXT NULL,
    "keywords" TEXT NULL,
    "last_access_time" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT(1697107687),
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);

CREATE TRIGGER delete_old_chat 
AFTER INSERT ON chats 

    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM chats) > 2 
    BEGIN 
         DELETE FROM chats 
         WHERE last_access_time = (SELECT MIN(last_access_time) 
                                   FROM chats);
END;
```

Right now there are already two entries in `chats`, so I just entered this query

```sql
insert into chats(id) values(abcd);
```

I get this error message.

> Runtime error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (19)

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

When you inserted a new row into `chats`, trigger fired. It concluded that count is larger than 2 and tried to **delete** row with the minimum `last_access_time`.

However, it seems that (at least one) row from `messages` **references** that row which caused the error. Because, if database let you delete that row, you'd get an *orphan* row - one whose parent doesn't exist any more.

Comment: which is why I have a constraint for cascade on delete

Comment: Right; but it means that - once you delete row from MESSAGES - it deletes its child rows from CHATS. But, trigger deletes from CHATS, not MESSAGES, so your ON DELETE CASCADE doesn't do anything.

Comment: But in this case the parent value is the `id` field from chats.

Comment: Yes, it is. So - if you delete that parent row, row(s) from MESSAGES are left orphans.

Comment: Littlefoot But the `ON DELETE CASCADE` constraint is added to the foreign key on *messages*.

Shouldn't that delete the rows with orphan fields?

Comment: **If** you ran DELETE FROM MESSAGES, ON DELETE CASCADE option would remove child rows from CHATS table. **However**, you are deleting from **CHATS** and ON DELETE CASCADE doesn't have any affect on that.